# How to add multiple table rows in awk

Tags: awk, html

Basically I am trying to print a table with 4 fields per row and the 5th field should go to the second row all the way to 8th field.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        FS=" "
        print "<HTML><BR><h2><CENTER><BODY> DETAILS </BODY></CENTER> </h2> <BR><CENTER><table border=1> <CENTER>"
        print "<TR><TH>No</TH><TH>Name</TH><TH>task</TH><TH>location</TH></TR>"
     }
     {
        printf "<TR>"
        for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)

        printf "<TD><CENTER>%s</CENTER></TD>", $i
        print "</TR>"

     }
     END{
        print "</TABLE></HTML>"
     }' /home/xyz/found.txt
```

I don't want the below which I am getting now. Its printing on the same row itself.

```
 No     Name   task  Location

 1001         Mike     Texting    US    1002  Mark  Chatting  UK
```

It should be

```
 No     Name   task  Location

 1001         Mike     Texting    US    
 1002         Mark     Chatting   UK
```

Could you please advise.

Comment: Where are you printing fields 1 through 4? I don't see it in the awk script

Answer (score 0):

You can print your file in rows every 4th field using something like this:

```
$ cat file7
abc,def,ghi,nop,klm,one,two,three,four,five,six,nine

$ awk -v RS="," '{printf("%s%s",$0,(NR%4==0?"\n":RS))}' file7
abc,def,ghi,nop
klm,one,two,three
four,five,six,nine
```

Using a custom RS (Record Separator) , you can make use of NR (line number) and handle each field of original file as a separate record/separate line.

If you need a header you can print the header in BEGIN section of awk.

PS: If your fields are separated by space, adjust RS (Record Separator) accordingly:

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '{printf("%s%s",$0,(NR%4==0?"\n":RS))}' file7
```